# Call a sagemaker inference endpoint using the java sdk v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to call a sagemaker inference endpoint from Java. I can do it without an issue from Python, running this after installing the `sagemaker` package:

```
predictor = TensorFlowPredictor('my-endpoint')
data = {'foo': 'bar'}
result = predictor.predict(data)
```

How can I do this using the latest official library? I'm assuming it is `software.amazon.awssdk:sagemaker:2.17.167`

There are similar questions on this site, but they seem to use an older version of the client. I also found a github repository with examples, but it does not show how to call an inference endpoint.

Comment: You are correct - that is the recommended API to use for this AWS Service. As you pointed out, there are existing code examples that show how to use this API. If the example you want does not exist, feel free to open an issue here and it will get into a Sprint and created. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples

Comment: If you do create a new issue requesting a code example, please be sure to describe the exact method in the Service Client JavaDocs you want... https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sagemaker/SageMakerClient.html

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 for the guidance, I will create an issue. I'm not sure about the exact method, I just need any way to call the endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. I was using the wrong library. For inference there is a separate "runtime" dependency: `software.amazon.awssdk:sagemakerruntime:2.17.167`

Something like this then works, this is Kotlin code:

```kotlin
val runtime = SageMakerRuntimeClient.builder()
    .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
    .build()

val requestString = """
    {"foo": "bar"}
"""

val request = InvokeEndpointRequest.builder()
    .endpointName("my-endpoint")
    .contentType("application/json")
    .body(SdkBytes.fromString(requestString, Charset.defaultCharset()))
    .build()

val response = runtime.invokeEndpoint(request)

println(response.body().asString(Charset.defaultCharset()))
```